# call openresty's nginx.conf file while running service start/stop/restart nginx command

Tags: nginx, openresty

I am using nginx as web server to my Django project.
I am using command

```
sudo service nginx start/stop/restart
```

to manage nginx server.
Now i am using Openresty framework to implement Lua code into nginx server to handle Cache system.
Openrestry provides it's own `nginx.conf` file.
Requirement : Now i want then when i run

```
sudo service nginx start/stop/restart
```

system should call nginx.conf file from Openresty folder(`/usr/local/openresty/nginx/conf/nginx.conf` in place of `/etc/nginx/nginx.confM` file.
How can i achieve this ???

Comment: How is that related to Lua?

Comment: Openresty framwork implement integration of lua with nginx .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should go to

```
cd /etc/init.d
```

```
vim nginx.conf
```

```
#Edit PATH , DAEMON variable
PATH=/usr/local/openresty/nginx/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
DAEMON=/usr/local/openresty/nginx/sbin/nginx
```

Now when you will run sudo service nginx start/stop/restart it will call nginx.conf file from openresty folder.
While /usr/local/openresty is the path where Openresty is installed by default

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread, but the author of openresty (agentzh) recommends creating a new openresty service by copying your `/etc/init.d/nginx` to `/etc/init.d/openrestify` and modifying the paths to match your custom openresty install. This is to prevent polluting your system's default config files. Please see [this mailing list post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/openresty-en/7UOz-y77CY4/qJ4O8VLZ_RUJ).

Answer (score 0):

Use the -c option:

```
  -c filename   : set configuration file (default: /etc/nginx/nginx.conf)
```

ie.

```
sudo service nginx -c /usr/local/openresty/nginx/conf/nginx.conf start/stop/restart
```

You can make an alias:

```
alias service_openresty="sudo service nginx -c /usr/local/openresty/nginx/conf/nginx.conf"
```

And run:

```
service_openresty start/stop/reload
```

This is the only safe approach because it won't get overwritten by package updates.

Comment: Please see my answer ..please let me know if my approach is wrong

Comment: does not work - I get this error: `Usage: nginx {start|stop|restart|reload|force-reload|status|configtest}`

Comment: You are probably not on the same distro.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use that nginx instead of your old nginx you can set

```
DAEMON_OPTS=" -c usr/local/openresty/nginx/conf/nginx.conf "
```

in "/etc/default/nginx"

In that case you can manage nginx as usual

```
sudo service nginx start/stop/restart
```

but your configuration in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf will not work.